# Can I rotate a WorldEdit selection horizontally?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit, minecraft-worldedit

I have a selection in WorldEdit (Bukkit Plugin) that I would like to rotate horizontally (i.e. not around in circles). I can use //rotate x to specify the angle to rotate, and using //rotate 180 would produce the effect as shown below, but I'd like to get the end result, to rotate it around a different axis (probably the y or x instead of z).

Is this possible within WorldEdit?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, Rotate command only rotates around Y axis(Or as you said, Z, depending where you draw them).

However, in here: http://redmine.sk89q.com/issues/633

It is suggested to use either

//deform rotate(axis1, axis2, degrees)

or

1. Select a cube containing your blocks. (height, width, depth on
   //size should be the same)
2. //deform swap(x,y)

Sources:

- http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldEdit/Clipboard#Rotating
- http://redmine.sk89q.com/issues/633

Comment: The "select a cube containing your blocks" was key here, because I tried with my original selection (something like 7x7x1) and it mangled it badly, but once I selected a cube it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

Yes this is possible:

```
//deform rotate(axis1, axis2, degrees)
```

So in your case, I think you want

```
//deform rotate(x,x,90)
```

I haven't got it installed at the moment, so unable to quickly check.

Another suggestion is `//deform swap(x,y)`

Answer (score 2):

The bukkit command is "//rotate (y axis)" by default, but you can go further by "//rotate  [(x axis) (z axis)]" so I rotated mine exactly like in your picture by typing in "//rotate 0 90 0" although you could spin it any way you want with that.

Comment: I wonder why this is undocumented. This works wonderfully!

Answer (score 1):

I know this might be a little late but with the rotate command you can do specific rotations with the command `//rotate y x z` (and yes it's y x z) and replace the z or x values with 90 or -90 in your situation. For example, you'd probably want to use `//rotate 0 90 0` or `//rotate 0 0 90` depending on the axis you want to rotate your build on.  Here's a [video](https://youtu.be/XYlg3vAjzLc) explaining the command more in depth. I hope this helps.